# Are there any good third party tools for making accurate shape layer from vector object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I tried using photoshop's "Color Range","Make Work Path", and "New Fill layer" tools to make a a shape layer that accurately recreae this vector image I want to recreate.

But all the results turned out terribly. Are there any good third party tools for making accurate shape layer from vector object?

Comment: Ermm... a vector object essentially **is** a "shape layer". Can you please give more detail and describe *exactly* what you are working with? Just guessing... do you have an embedded vector smart object that you want to turn into a shape layer? Do you have a vector editor - Illustrator, Inkscape? Photoshop has some vector *tools and features* but it's not really a vector *editor*.

Comment: What what is the file format of the vector object?

Comment: To be clear... *with* a vector editor, turning a vector smart object into a shape layer is merely a matter of copy/pasting - Copy while using the vector editor.. paste as shape layer in Photoshop. *Without* a vector editor, well, there's no method as good as the copy/pasting much of the time. Inkscape is free.. so I guess to *possibly* answer the question.. that may be the best "3rd party tool"

Comment: @BillyKerr Its in a png format

Comment: PNG isn't a vector format. It's a raster format.  What you'd probably be better doing is trace it in Illustrator or Inkscape.  Both have auto tracing capabilities.  Other than than, creating it manual with the pen tool might actually be the best option.